# how to queue animation slide when it is looped using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

here i am trying to make animation in which 1st image should slide and next second image and then third image and so on but now all of them are being animated at a time any help what to do.?

```
<script>
 $(window).load(function(){
    $(".frame-container").each(function(){

   var frameheight=$(this).innerHeight();
   var framewidth=$(this).innerWidth();

    var refRatio = framewidth/frameheight;
   var imgH = $(this).children("img").height();
   var imgW = $(this).children("img").width();

   if ( (imgW/imgH) < refRatio ) {

        //  $(this).addClass("portrait");
         var moveImage = (imgH - frameheight)/2;
    //alert(moveImage);
        $(this).children("img").css({'position':'relative','top':'-'+moveImage+'px'});
         $(this).children("img").animate({ top: '-100px',position:'relative' }, 5000 );

   } else {
         // alert(refRatio+"@@@@@"+(imgW/imgH));
       //   $(this).addClass("landscape");
       var moveImage = (imgW - framewidth)/2;
//alert(moveImage);
         $(this).children("img").css({'position':'relative','left':'-'+moveImage+'px'});
 $(this).children("img").animate({  left: '-100px','position':'relative' }, 5000 );
   }
});
     });
</script>




    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="box1 frame-container">
           <img src="images/8.JPG"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="box2 frame-container"><img src="images/9.JPG"  /></div>
        </div>
     </div>


     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="box3 frame-container"><img src="images/10.JPG"  /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="box4 frame-container"><img src="images/11.jpg"  /></div>
            <div class="box5 frame-container"><img src="images/12.JPG" /></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sliding all the images at once using this code:

```
$(this).children("img").animate({ top: '-100px',position:'relative' }, 5000 );
```

Slide next after the first has completed it's slide animation, using this code:

```
var images = $(this).children("img");
var counter = 0;
function slideImage()
{
    if(counter < images.length)
    {
        $(images[counter]).animate(
            { top: '-100px',position:'relative' },
            5000,
            function(){
                slideImage();
            }
        );
        counter++;
    }
}
slideImage();
```

**EDIT:**
To mainatain the animation, add the following code after `counter++;`:

```
if(counter >= images.length)
    counter = 0;
```

Comment: how can i maintain this animation for ever i have been trying to call function in a function but its not happennig

Comment: @3bu1 Please see I have added the solution above.